# How do I prepend the drop down arrow on a parent v-list-group expansion panel?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm trying to prepend the drop down arrow on a `v-list-group` and append a search icon. It's working, but the search icon flips when the list is opened and not the dropdown icon like is to be expected

```
<v-list-group
    v-for="item in items"
    :key="item.title"
    prepend-icon="$expand"
    append-icon="search"
    v-model="item.active"
    no-action
>
    <template v-slot:activator v-slot:prependIcon>
    <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title"></v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
    </template>

    <v-list-item
    v-for="child in item.items"
    :key="child.title"
    >
    <v-list-item-avatar>
        <v-img max-height="30" max-width="30" :src="child.avatar"></v-img>
    </v-list-item-avatar>
    <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title v-text="child.title"></v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
</v-list-group>
```

How do I fix this?

[Codepen example.](https://codepen.io/Corbin/pen/RwRqVbx?editors=1010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the solution I added the `sub-group` property to the list group and added the icon in the activator slot via `v-list-item-icon`.

```html
<v-list-group
  v-for="item in items"
  :key="item.title"
  prepend-icon="$expand"
  v-model="item.active"
  no-action
  sub-group
>
  <template v-slot:activator>
    <v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title"></v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
    <v-list-item-icon>
      <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
    </v-list-item-icon>
  </template>

  <v-list-item
    v-for="child in item.items"
    :key="child.title"
  >
    <v-list-item-avatar>
      <v-img
        max-height="30"
        max-width="30"
        :src="child.avatar"
      ></v-img>
    </v-list-item-avatar>
    <v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-title v-text="child.title"></v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
  </v-list-item>
</v-list-group>
```

`sub-group` isn't very well documented but apparently it moves the expand icon to the left.

Comment: I tried using `sub-group` before and it was indenting strangely in other lists, I'm not sure if it was an issue with margin or padding (I can check). But I tried your solution and I'm having the width of the card expand:

https://codepen.io/Corbin/pen/jOrQjpm?editors=1010

Comment: Wrap the v-card component in a `div`.

Comment: Awesome thank you. I had to make some CSS changes as well, so it would work out normally. If you want to make an edit with those that'd be cool.

https://codepen.io/Corbin/pen/ExyGEdR?editors=1010